# How to write nth line below specific text in VBS

Tags: vbscript

In a text file consisting of thousands of records, each having greater than 20 lines of data, I need to count the 14th line after the start of every record if that 14th line is blank. The line is either blank or contains a date.

The start of every record is the same: "1 Start of new record"

Scenario:

1 Start of new record
2 some data 
3 " 
4 "  
5 " 
6 " 
7 " 
8 " 
9 " 
10 "
11 " 
12 " 
13 " 
14 
... 
1 Start of new record 
... 
8 " 
9 " 
10 " 
...  
14 10/19/2019
 
...

In this simple scenario, the result should be 1. I have code that copies line 1 of every record into a second file.

The result obviously being:

1 Start of new record
1 Start of new record
...

Here is the code I have:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Dim words(1)

Dim msg

words(0) = "1  Start of New Record"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set inFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\Temp\altest.txt", ForReading)

Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\Temp\altest_output.txt", 8, True)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream

    strSearchString = inFile.ReadLine

    For i = 0 To UBound(words)-1

    If InStr(strSearchString,words(i)) Then

   msg = msg&strSearchString&vbcrlf

    End If

    next

Loop

inFile.Close

outfile.WriteLine msg

WScript.Echo "Done!"
```

This seems like a good start, but again, I need to count the 14th line after the start of every record if that 14th line is blank.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
-Alel

Comment: You did not mention what the problem is. Please include that in your question.

Comment: Hi Arno van Boven. It appears that my issue was listed too early in the post. I have edited to restate the goal at the end of the post, as well.  Thank you. -Alel

Comment: When you found a new record start, why not just keep reading until you've read the next 14 lines? Of SkipLine 14 times? (you would have to move `outfile.WriteLine` to the inside of the loop). Also, if indeed the start new record is literally "1  Start of New Record", the check on that can be simplified to just match the string. If the "1" in there can change, you could match the right n characters.

Comment: I confess that I am new to vbscript. The code I have was found online and I slightly modified it thinking I could make it work. Your recommendation certainly sounds logical; however, my fumbling through it is resulting in empty text files and/or script errors. May I trouble you for an example of how to implement the SkipLine method into the code I have provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardly elegant but something like this should get you on your way. This doesn't use `SkipLine`, it just marks the next line of interest:

```
Option Explicit 'force explicit variable declaration, this is just good practice

Const ForReading = 1

Dim strContent
Dim Offset : Offset = 14 'define the 14th 'line'
Dim StartLine

Dim NewRecordMarker : NewRecordMarker = "1 Start of new record" 'just use a string to match

Dim objFSO, inFile, outFile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("e:\Temp\altest.txt", ForReading)
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("e:\Temp\altest_output.txt", 8, True)

'notice we're only reading forward
'that means we can set the next LineOfInterest without having to worry about
'exceeding AtEndOfStream like we would if we'd use SkipLine
'this is just simpler.
'this obviously falls apart when the line of interest is NOT the 14th line
Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    Dim LineOfInterest
    strContent = inFile.ReadLine 'inFile.Line will at 2 at this point because we just read it

    If strContent = NewRecordMarker Then 'found a new record, we want to look 14 lines from here
        LineOfInterest = inFile.line - 1 + Offset ' -1 or we'll overshoot our target
    End If

    If inFile.Line = LineOfInterest Then 'this is the line we want to inspect
        outFile.WriteLine strContent 'just write out entire value, no checking for date here
    End If
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close

WScript.Echo "Done!"
```

Comment: Hello Arno van Boven! Your answer doesn't have to be elegant. It scanned 180000 lines of text in about 1 second and created a file containing the exact information I've been trying to get. Thanks so much for taking the time to share your knowledge and help out a fellow programmer. You're my hero!